flask cant get form data , or get wrong from data
When I was using flask for development, I encountered a strange problem. When I wanted to parse the HTML form, it would either be empty or an error.
here is my html
            <form class="login-form" id="upload-form" method="POST" action="/login">

            <div class="field">
            <input required class="password" type="text" placeholder="USER" name='user' >

            <input class="password" type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD(optional)" name='password' >


            <input class="submit -button" value="login" type="submit">
            </div>

          </form>

my flask
login_bp = Blueprint('login',__name__,url_prefix='/login')
@login_bp.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def login():
    ip = request.remote_addr
    username = request.form.get('user')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    command = f'sshpass -p {password} ssh {username}@{ip}'
    try:
        #subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True)
        return render_template('index.html')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        return render_template('login.html',login_statu="login fail")

i got this
[2024-04-10 10:39:27,052] DEBUG in a: form=ImmutableMultiDict([('\r\n\r\nuser', 'c'), ('passw', '')])

i change to
user = request.args.get('user')
but it got same error

i want to solve this problem, how can i do,change html or flask?

Simply add a print statement to see it yourself. The Logger will never print your password.
